# MySQL DB Connection Issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to mysql db using Airflow MySqlOperator operator.
It is giving an error:

`MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'hostname1'`

The hostname i.e. hostname1 showing up in the error is totally different that the hostname (let's call it hostname2) that I entered in the Admin-> Connection console which is usually used to enter all credentials.

After reading few post on dba.stackexchange, I executed the following command `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER()` in mysql workbench using username and hostname2 and I get a 3rd totally different hostname(let's call it hostname3) for both user() and current_user().

The airflow code to connect to mysql db was working perfectly fine last month. I have made no changes to the code or any configuration. So I am thinking it has to do with the database. If someone has any pointers as to how to fix/debug it, it would be great.

Comment: `hostname1` is where your application connects _from_, not where it connects _to_.

Comment: Sorry @mustaccio I didn't follow. Should I be reaching to the Database admin to see if he can somehow add/provide grants to hostname1 for username on that DB.

Comment: Yes, `username`  should be granted the permission to connect from `hostname1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain a little further your scenario; first, you need to know that  in MySQL you can have multiple users (with the same name) but different IP / hostnames; see the example below:

```
mysql> SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='test';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER test@20.20.20.20 IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rd.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER test@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rd.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER test@10.10.10.10 IDENTIFIED BY 'Passw0rd.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='test';
+------+-------------+
| user | host        |
+------+-------------+
| test | 10.10.10.10 |
| test | 20.20.20.20 |
| test | localhost   |
+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I log in with the test user from localhost, I'll be able to connect:

```
# mysql -u test -pPassw0rd. -h 127.0.0.1  -e "SELECT USER()"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+----------------+
| USER()         |
+----------------+
| test@localhost |
+----------------+
```

But if I remove the localhost user, I'm unable to connect (even though the user test still exists):

```
mysql> DROP USER test@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='test';
+------+-------------+
| user | host        |
+------+-------------+
| test | 10.10.10.10 |
| test | 20.20.20.20 |
+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

# mysql -u test -pPassw0rd. -h 127.0.0.1  -e "SELECT USER()"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

With the example above I hope it's clearer for you what's the issue; you can see the error you shared is the same as mine at the end; your "username" doesn't exist in your MySQL; so you should ask your DBA to create the user with required privileges for that particular "hostname1".
You could either share with your DBA the error; or ask him/her to check if your "hostname1" exists when executing the following:

```
SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='YOUR_USERNAME';
```

Finally, you can check further details on this "hostname" situation [here in the MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html).